# Attempted to call an undefined method named "setName"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I couldn't persist an object to the database.

This is the error:
[image: link to error]

This is the DefaultController which is situated on AppBundle\Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ]);
    }
/**
 * @Route("/content", name="db")
 */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
        $product->setPrice('19.99');
        $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
    }
}
```

And this is the Product entity on AppBundle\Entity with the field name:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;
    

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your entity?

Comment: Obviously you have no `setName` method in your entity (`Product` class)

Comment: I have added my entity

Answer (score 4):

You are having this error because :

- Product entity haven't a setter setName
- You are loading the wrong entity class check the use namespace

Comment: I have added entity . Maybe you're able to look through ?

Comment: you need to add setters and getters to your entity setName, setPrice and setDescription also the getters

Comment: I have added them like this **php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product**

Comment: Did you follow this?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html  Did you perform all 3 Doctrine commands?

Answer (score 3):

It's a straight forward error because you didn't generate your getters and setters. Take a look at this [Generating Getters and Setters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters).

This is what you have to do:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product
```

Comment: I have generated that 
# generates all entities in the AppBundle
**$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle**

Comment: I see you are already following the documentation. You should generate them again but now only for the entity Product. "This is a safe command - you can run it over and over again."

Comment: did you try adding them yourself?

Comment: Just type in the code that you need.

`function getName() { return $this->name; }
function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }`